# Make Sweave + RweaveHTML put all graphics in a specified folder

Tags: r, sweave

As a refinement of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674567/how-to-make-sweave-copy-generated-graphics-to-a-subfolder), does anyone know how to tell Sweave (or better the driver) to put all the graphics in a specific directory when using the `RweaveHTML` driver from the `R2HTML` package? I can't find any option for that :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweave responds to the `prefix.string` option for figures. E.g. in one recent document I use

```
\SweaveOpts{engine=R,eps=FALSE,echo=TRUE,prefix.string=figures/chart}
```

which leads to files `figures/chart-chunkname.pdf` where I use `chunkname` as the identifier in the Sweave code snippet.  I suspect the same may help for [R2HTML](http://cran.r-project.org/package=R2HTML) but I have not tried that driver.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. For reference you do it like this `<<echo=TRUE,fig=TRUE,prefix.string=graphics/mypic>>=`

Comment: That would be per-snippet -- what I use is a global option so that you do need to set it again for each code snippet.