# How to get Sweave to put graphics in separate folder AND name them after the Rnw file

Tags: r, sweave

I've seen a few questions about this, but can't work out how to do what I want.

By default, Sweave creates graphics by concatenating the name of the Rnw file and the name of the graphic object label.

From this question ([Make Sweave + RweaveHTML put all graphics in a specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678888/make-sweave-rweavehtml-put-all-graphics-in-a-specified-folder)) If I want all my graphics in the folder foo and to be named bar-graphic I can use

```
\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=foo/bar}
```

But how can I get the graphics in folder foo but named rnwfile-graphic ?

Comment: Am guessing you want to know how to do this programatically instead of just manually replacing `bar` with the filename (minus extension) of the Rnw file you are editing/writing?

Comment: Yes, ideally, although as you say, I could just update this for each new sweave file.

Comment: You could use `brew()` from the brew package to generate a `filename.Rnw` programmatically, with the `filename` fragment  inserted into the Sweave source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, this probably should be assigned to the innermost circle of hell, but the only way I know of to get the name of the currently running script is to use (abuse?) the source reference attached to functions. Consider this Sweave chunk in a file `foo.Rnw`

```
<<>>=
foo <- function(x) {x}
srcref <- attr(body(foo), "srcref")[[1]]
attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename
@
```

When I process `foo.Rnw` with Sweave I get:

```
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> foo <- function(x) {
+     x
+ }
> srcref <- attr(body(foo), "srcref")[[1]]
> attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] "foo.Rnw"
attr(,"encoding")
[1] "ASCII"
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
```

You could make a dummy function at the top of your Sweave file, pull out the `$filename` from the source reference, and process it to remove the extension, e.g.:

```
> sub("\\.Rnw", "", "foo.Rnw")
[1] "foo"
```

and then build up the string needed for `prefix.string`, with say

```
<<>>=
fname <- sub("\\.Rnw", "", attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename)
prefix.string <- paste("foo/", fname, "-graphic", sep = "")
@

\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=\Sexpr{prefix.string}}
```

where `prefix.string` contains the built up path and prefix.

Here is a complete example:

```
<<>>=
foo <- function(x) {x}
srcref <- attr(body(foo), "srcref")[[1]]
attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename
@

<<>>=
fname <- sub("\\.Rnw", "", attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename)
prefix.string <- paste("foo/", fname, "-graphic", sep = "")
@

\SweaveOpts{prefix.string=\Sexpr{prefix.string}}

<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(1:10)
@
```

that when processed by Sweave gives:

```
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> foo <- function(x) {
+     x
+ }
> srcref <- attr(body(foo), "srcref")[[1]]
> attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] "foo.Rnw"
attr(,"encoding")
[1] "ASCII"
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> fname <- sub("\\.Rnw", "", attr(srcref, "srcfile")$filename)
> prefix.string <- paste("foo/", fname, "-graphic", sep = "")
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}



\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> plot(1:10)
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}
\includegraphics{foo/foo-graphic-003}
```

Tweak that as you see fit.

Comment: That's quite a hack.  I had no idea that sourcing a function was any different than just typing it at the console.

Comment: Gavin, I'm curious if you saw my solution; it doesn't have any votes yet so I wondered if there's a reason not to do it that way.  Hoping this doesn't come across as fishing for votes...

Comment: @Aaron I did, but I've been ill for a few days and not up to much SO activity. The only comment I have is that this is not automagic; your solution requires, IIUC, for the user to insert the name of the subdirectory (I suppose this could be the script name too as the OP asked) in the `\SweaveOpts{}`. If so, you can do this with `prefix` anyway, can't you? In the comments to the Q, the OP mentioned that automating this from the scriptname would be an ideal.

Comment: @Aaron that said, your Answer is a nice illustration of how a simple modification can be made to a driver in order to add user facilities/functionality. I haven't seen many examples of this. So I'll +1 just for that.

Comment: Gavin, sorry to hear you've been sick; I hope you're feeling better.  As I understand, the OP wanted `bar` to be the name of the script automagically, which is default Sweave behavior, but then to define a subdirectory `foo` for the files to go in, so the `foo` couldn't be automagic.

Answer (score 3):

While Gavin's hack is great, if you really want Sweave to do different sorts of things, the best way to do so is to write your own driver; I use this method, for instance, for getting Sweave to scale different figures differently.  You don't have to start from scratch but can just modify the existing code as needed.

There's only a couple minor functions that need to be changed for this case, however, with the namespace issues it's easier to just start with all the Sweave code; you can get [the 2.13 Sweave code here](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-2-13-branch/src/library/utils/R/).

The necessary changes are below.  They add a new option, `subdir`, and prepend it to the original `chunkprefix`, which is the name of the rnw file. The `SweaveParseOptions` line is needed because this function is not exported by `utils` and is in a different source file.

```
16a17,18
> SweaveParseOptions <- utils:::SweaveParseOptions
> 
69c71
<                     concordance = FALSE, expand = TRUE, figs.only = FALSE)
---
>                     concordance = FALSE, expand = TRUE, figs.only = FALSE, subdir=".")
520c522
<                    "grdevice")
---
>                    "grdevice", "subdir")
568c570
<     chunkprefix
---
>     file.path(options$subdir, chunkprefix)
```

With the changes saved as `SweaveDriversNew.R`, put the option in your `Rnw` file like this

```
\SweaveOpts{subdir=foo}
```

And then Sweave using the new driver like this.

```
source("SweaveDriversNew.R")
Sweave("test.Rnw", driver=RweaveLatex)
```

The result is that images are named `foo/test-graphic.pdf`, where `foo` is defined in the Sweave file and `test` is automagically taken from the name of Sweave file.